# Hibernate: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, hibernate

I have tried many things which were mentioned in the thread. But none seem to solve my problem. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

**Models**

```
@Entity
public class MySession {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique=true)
    private String sessionId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="session")
    private List<MyRequest> requestList;

}

@Entity
public class MyRequest{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    private MySession session;
}
```

**In my servlet:**

```
SessionHome sh = new SessionHome();               //DAO Class
MyRequestHome mrh = new MyRequestHome();          //DAO Class

MySession session = sh.findBySessionId(sessionId);  //Object is in the detached state
session.setUpdated(new Date());             //Update the Session update time stamp  
session = sh.merge(session);                    //Update the database with the session. I was hoping merge would reattach the detached object

MyRequest mr = new MyRequest(hsrequest, newSessionToken);
mr.setSession(session);
mrh.persist(mr);                                    //PersistentObjectException here. This is because of the MySession object I have set over here.
```

Firstly, I get the MySession Object from the database, update it and set it in the newly created MyRequest object. When I try to persist the MyRequest object it gives me the PersistentObjectException. Please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378526/org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by calling Merge on the transient MyRequest instance.

Before:

```
mrh.persist(mr);
```

After:

```
mrh.merge(mr);
```

Please let me know if there are any drawbacks in doing in this way.