# Can't persist my objects

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

here's is the problem

I have  a java class Agence that has a `@ManytoOne` relationship with my class Reseau .

there is my Agence code :

```
package ma.kafil.bank;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
public class Agence implements Serializable{

    private int idAgence;
    private String labelle;
    private Reseau reseau;

    public Agence(String labelle) {
    this.labelle = labelle;
    }



    public Agence() {
    }

    @ManyToOne
    public Reseau getReseau() {
    return reseau;
    }

    public void setReseau(Reseau reseau) {
    this.reseau = reseau;
    }



    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getIdAgence() {
    return idAgence;
    }

    public void setIdAgence(int idAgence) {
    this.idAgence = idAgence;
    }

    public String getLabelle() {
    return labelle;
    }

    public void setLabelle(String labelle) {
    this.labelle = labelle;
    }



}
```

and my Reseau Class :

```
    package ma.kafil.bank;

    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
    import javax.persistence.Id;
    import javax.persistence.OneToMany;


    @Entity
    public class Reseau implements Serializable{
        private int idReseau;
        private String Libelle;
        private ArrayList<Agence> Agences = new ArrayList();

        //Constructor without arguments
        public Reseau() {
        }

        public Reseau(String Libelle) {
        this.Libelle = Libelle;
        }

        public void ajouterAgence(Agence a){
        Agences.add(a);
        }


        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        public int getIdReseau() {
        return idReseau;
        }

        public void setIdReseau(int idReseau) {
        this.idReseau = idReseau;
        }

        public String getLibelle() {
        return Libelle;
        }

        public void setLibelle(String Libelle) {
        this.Libelle = Libelle;
        }


      @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}, mappedBy="reseau")
        public Collection<Agence> getAgences() {
        return Agences;
        }



        public void setAgences(ArrayList<Agence> Agences) {
        this.Agences = Agences;
        }

        public void addAgence(Agence a){
        this.Agences.add(a);
        }





    }
```

And Finally the main class :

```
package ma.kafil.bank;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
    //Creating Entity Manager 
    //persistence-unit name="test"

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    //beginning the transaction
    em.getTransaction().begin();


    //Creating a new Reseau r with  r.labbelle = "Centre" and r.id=1
    Reseau r = new Reseau("Centre");
    r.setIdReseau(1);

    //Creating a new Agence a 
    Agence a = new Agence("Nom Agence");
    a.setIdAgence(2);

    //adding a to my Reseau (What's the problem with that ?? )
    r.addAgence(a);
    em.persist(r);

    a.setIdAgence(1990);
    a.setReseau(r);

    em.persist(a);
    em.getTransaction().commit();

    //closing em and emf 
    em.close();
    emf.close();



    }

}
```

Here is the stack trace :

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ma.kafil.bank.Reseau
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:637)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
    at ma.kafil.bank.Main.main(Main.java:30)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ma.kafil.bank.Reseau
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:38)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:618)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:592)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:596)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:220)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

And here is persistence.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">   <persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class> ma.kafil.bank.Agence</class>
    <class> ma.kafil.bank.Reseau</class>

    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/awbawards"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
    </properties>
       </persistence-unit> </persistence>
```

## Thanks in Advance

Comment: please post stack trace

Comment: Please post persistence.xml, I believe there lays the problem. I think there is no persistence unit named "test" defined correctly

Comment: I don't think that is the problem

Comment: my bad seems the persistence.xml is ok. I've seen the problem ... you can only persist one object the next ones will be "dirty" persists and you have to use merge (the effect will be the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your reseau class, the agences list is never initialized, it should be:

```
    @Entity
    public class Reseau implements Serializable{
        private int idReseau;
        private String Libelle;
        private List<Agence> Agences = new ArrayList<Agence>();
```

Also your field, getter and setter declarations should all use the type List, not Collection not ArrayList and your field shouldn't start with a capital letter (java naming conventions):

```
    private List<Agence> agences = new ArrayList<Agence>();

    public List<Agence> getAgences() {
      return agences;
    }

    public void setAgences(List<Agence> agences) {
      this.agences = agences;
    }
```

Comment: But then I get this :

`
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: ma.kafil.bank.Reseau
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:637)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
 at ma.kafil.bank.Main.main(Main.java:30)`

Comment: This one is another problem but his solutions is what you need to get past the `NPE` that you're getting now.
Try removing any `a.setIdAgence(...);` line and see if it gives you the new exception

Comment: Why should I use `ArrayList` and not collection and `ArrayList` ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you do `r.addAgence(a);` it is possible that list of `Agences` is null for few `Reseau`. A quick fix can be done in your add method -

```
public void addAgence(Agence a){
   if(Agences==null){//do this check to avoid null pointer
      Agences = new ArrayList<Agence>();
   }
   this.Agences.add(a);
}
```

Comment: I still have this problem : detached entity passed to persist: ma.kafil.bank.Reseau

Comment: this is a different problem which not related to your earlier null pointer exception.

Comment: see this link for detach entity persistance problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378526/org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist

Answer (score 0):

Since you edited your question I'll post it as an answer.

Based on this reply https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442036/1094430 you should not set your ID by code if you DB is set to auto generate them.

So remove

```
r.setIdReseau(1);
...
a.setIdAgence(2);
...
a.setIdAgence(1990);
```

from your code and then do the persist.

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException:` org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of ma.kafil.bank.Reseau.agences
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.throwPersistenceException(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:637)
 at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:226)
 at ma.kafil.bank.Main.main(Main.java:29)

Comment: @Kafil10 your getter and setter are not correct, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Try with this main:

```
package ma.kafil.bank;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
    //Creating Entity Manager 
    //persistence-unit name="test"

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    //beginning the transaction
    em.getTransaction().begin();


    //Creating a new Reseau r with  r.labbelle = "Centre" and r.id=1
    Reseau r = new Reseau("Centre");
    r.setIdReseau(1);

    //Creating a new Agence a 
    Agence a = new Agence("Nom Agence");
    a.setIdAgence(2);
    a.setIdAgence(1990);
    a.setReseau(r);    

    //adding a to my Reseau (What's the problem with that ?? )
    r.addAgence(a);
    em.persist(r);

    em.getTransaction().commit();

    //closing em and emf 
    em.close();
    emf.close();



    }

}
```

It should work, because both objects are linked.