# Troubles with updating hibernate entity

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to configure many-to-one relationship between dish and restaurant. Create/read/delete operations work properly, but I face this error when I'm trying to update dish entity:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: org.polik.votingsystem.model.Dish
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:760) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:746) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.5.Final.jar:5.6.5.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy115.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy115.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:637) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:529) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:639) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:163) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:138) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
```

Dish entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "dishes")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Dish extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    @NotNull
    private Integer price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "restaurant_id")
    private Restaurant restaurant;

    @Column(name = "date")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDate date;

    public Dish(Integer id, String name, Integer price) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Dish(Integer id, String name, Integer price, Restaurant restaurant, LocalDate date) {
        super(id);
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.restaurant = restaurant;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

restaurant entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "restaurant")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Restaurant extends BaseEntity {
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String name;
}
```

base entity

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@Access(AccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Persistable<Integer> {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;

    public BaseEntity(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isNew() {
        return id != null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || !getClass().equals(Hibernate.getClass(o))) {
            return false;
        }
        BaseEntity that = (BaseEntity) o;
        return id != null && id.equals(that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id;
    }
}
```

update method

```java
@Transactional
public void update(DishTo dishTo, int id) {
    Dish dish = new Dish(
            id,
            dishTo.getName(),
            dishTo.getPrice(),
            getRestaurantById(dishTo.getRestaurantId()),
            LocalDate.now()
    );

    log.info("update {}", dish);

    checkNotFound(repository.save(dish), "id=" + id);
}
```

What I've tried:

1. change cascadetype
2. change generatedstrategy
3. set fetchtype to eager

Comment: Your problem seems like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6378526/org-hibernate-persistentobjectexception-detached-entity-passed-to-persist Can you check on that?

Comment: But here you should find what you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4438358/2846138 - you have a detached _dish_ because it's from a transfer object (or does suffix TO mean something different), so it means in the database there should be a dish entity with the same ID. That answer discusses how to re-attach it. Be sure to read other answers there as well.

Comment: @cyberbrain thank you, but i accidentally found that it works properly if i initialize dish in update method by setters.

Comment: Please don't add things like "solved" to your question title. Instead, post an answer, and accept it after the timeout. Acceptance of an answer is what signals a question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved. Right now, I absolutely have no idea why, but when I changed dish initialization from constructor to setter, it started working properly.

Solution:

```java
@Transactional
public void update(DishTo dishTo, int id) {
    log.info("update {} {}", dishTo, id);
    Dish dish = new Dish();
    ValidationUtil.assureIdConsistent(dish, id);

    dish.setName(dishTo.getName());
    dish.setPrice(dishTo.getPrice());
    dish.setRestaurant(
            getRestaurantById(dishTo.getRestaurantId())
    );

    repository.save(dish);
}
```

Comment: you should add an example to your answer, and then you can accept your own answer - instead of editing the title.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).