# Spring data + Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data and Hibernate and get an error when I'm trying to save entity with set id:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.snp.cm.persistency.contact.Contact; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.snp.cm.persistency.contact.Contact
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:668)
```

Please help me how can I update an entity via JpaRepositories or what config do I miss?

persistence.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
<persistence-unit name="contactManagerPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>

    <class>com.snp.cm.persistency.contact.Contact</class>
    <class>com.snp.cm.persistency.contact.TelephoneNumber</class>

    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

spring context:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
default-lazy-init="true">

<import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/dbs-repository-context.xml" />

<!-- Activates JPA's @PersistenceContext and @PersistenceUnit (if available) 
    annotations to be detected in bean classes. -->
<context:annotation-config />

<!-- Enable Transaction using @Transactional annotation -->
<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="daTM"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<!-- Create local transaction manager -->
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" lazy-init="true"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" />

<!-- Create EntityManagerFactory for injection into services. -->
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:persistenceXmlLocation-ref="persistenceXmlLocation">
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Database access configuration -->
<bean id="persistenceXmlLocation" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml"></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath:META-INF/spring/jdbc.properties" />

<!-- Dev's env DataSource -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
```

I used OpenJpa in another project and didn't have such issue: 'save' methode did create and update if an entity has set id. So how can I update an object? Should I implement my own update methode?

Failed test:

```
@Test
public void testRepositorySaveMethod() {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setLastName("Carter");
    contact.setName("John");
    contact.setNickName(null);
    contact = this.contactRepository.save(contact);
    Assert.assertNotNull(contact.getContactId());

    TelephoneNumber telephoneNumber1 = new TelephoneNumber();
    telephoneNumber1.setTelephoneNumber("777 7777777");
    telephoneNumber1.setContact(contact);
    telephoneNumber1.setTelephoneType(TelephoneType.HOME);
    this.telephoneNumberRepository.save(telephoneNumber1);    // failes cause contact has already id

    contact = this.contactRepository.findOne(contact.getContactId());

    Assert.assertEquals(1, contact.getTelephoneNumbers().size());
}
```

Comment: You need to show some code. You have only provided the configurations for your ORM and beans here. The root cause is surely your code.

Answer (score 4):

The reason is the following. The `save(…)` method of the repository proxy is a transactional one. As you have a `JpaTransactionManager` configured the lifecycle of the Hibernate `Session` is bound to the transaction. This results in the `Session` (and transaction) being closed when the call returns from `save(…)` in your test case. Thus the entity is not attached to the `Session` anymore which causes the exception you see later on.

The solution in test cases usually is to mark the test method as `@Transactional`. Assuming you're using the Spring test context framework, this will cause a transaction (and thus a `Session`) being opened (and held open) for the entire test method.

Aside from that, the declaration of the `DataSourceTransactionManager` is obsolete as you don't seem to use it anywhere.

Comment: yeah, thanks a lot, you are right. Hm, but now I got an error on last assert cause my @OneToMany relationship does not work.

Comment: @Snoopman Because the telephone collection is lazily loaded and the session is already closed when assert is called. Did you mark the test method with `@Transactional` as Oliver suggested?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is said by: `detached entity passed to persist`

Probably you are trying to do something like below:

```
Entity detachedEntity = getDetachedEntitySomehow();
em.persist(detachedEntity); // it is causing error.
```

It seems `id` is set for your entity any trying to be updated using `persist`.

You can take a look at this answer too: [“detached entity passed to persist error” with JPA/EJB code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code)