# error during MassIndexer operation : detached entity passed to persist, HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000116

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, indexing, hibernate-search

I've got an issue during massindexer operation.

I use JPA 2.0-cr-1, Hibernate search 4.2.0.Final with hibernate 4.1.9.Final, and lucene version 3.6.2.
I also use spring framework.

It seems that I've got issues since I use Hibernate search 4.2.0.Final in place of Hibernate search 3.3.0.Final.

I indexed entity User.java :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "email"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "login") })
@Indexed
@FullTextFilterDefs({
@FullTextFilterDef(name = "userFilterGroup", impl = UserFilterGroupFactory.class   ,cache=FilterCacheModeType.NONE),
@FullTextFilterDef(name = "userFilterAccountType", impl = LuceneStrFilterFactory.class ,cache=FilterCacheModeType.NONE)})
public class User extends TemporalBehavior implements java.io.Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -626437341655804022L;


public static final String[] SEARCH_FIELDS = new String[]{"id","login","email","profile.lastname","profile.firstname"};

private Integer id;

@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
@NotNull
@Size(min=1, max=255)
//@Size(min=6, max=255) //L'ancienne plateforme permet des login min=1
private String login;

@NotNull
@Size(min=1, max=255)
//@Size(min=6, max=255) //L'ancienne plateforme permet des pass min=1
private String password;

@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
@Email
private String email;

@Field(index=Index.YES, analyze=Analyze.YES, store=Store.NO)
private String partnerRef;

private Set<Contract> contracts = new HashSet<Contract>(0);
private Set<Contract> ownedContracts = new HashSet<Contract>();

    ....
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinTable(name = "user_contract", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "contract_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Contract> getContracts() {
    return this.contracts;
}

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="owner")
public Set<Contract> getOwnedContracts() {
    return this.ownedContracts;
}

    ...

    }
```

Massindexer operation I called :

```
FullTextEntityManager fem = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    try {
        fem.createIndexer(User.class)
        .purgeAllOnStart(true)
        .optimizeAfterPurge( true )   
        .optimizeOnFinish( true )
        .batchSizeToLoadObjects(100)  
        .threadsForSubsequentFetching(8)  
        .threadsToLoadObjects(4)  
        .cacheMode(CacheMode.NORMAL)    // todo : It is recommended to leave cacheMode to CacheMode.IGNORE (the default), as in most reindexing situations the cache will be a useless additional overhead; 
        .startAndWait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Then the massindexer do its work but there is some errors (not for all User data) :

```
[05-02-2013 13:06:11:086] ERROR org.hibernate.search.exception.impl.LogErrorHandler  -   HSEARCH000058: HSEARCH000116: Unexpected error during MassIndexer operation
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:   com.mycompany.prj.model.commercial.Contract
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:141)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:78)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer$IncrediblySillyJpaMapsIdMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:491)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:337)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4491)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLockEventListener.onLock(DefaultLockEventListener.java:73)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:810)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:799)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1700(SessionImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$LockRequestImpl.lock(SessionImpl.java:2361)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$2.cascade(CascadingAction.java:178)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:383)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:412)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:353)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:329)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLockEventListener.cascadeOnLock(DefaultLockEventListener.java:92)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLockEventListener.onLock(DefaultLockEventListener.java:82)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:810)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:799)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1700(SessionImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$LockRequestImpl.lock(SessionImpl.java:2361)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$2.cascade(CascadingAction.java:178)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:383)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLockEventListener.cascadeOnLock(DefaultLockEventListener.java:92)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLockEventListener.onLock(DefaultLockEventListener.java:82)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:810)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLock(SessionImpl.java:803)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1800(SessionImpl.java:175)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$LockRequestImpl.lock(SessionImpl.java:2364)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.EntityConsumerLuceneWorkProducer.indexAllQueue(EntityConsumerLuceneWorkProducer.java:133)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.EntityConsumerLuceneWorkProducer.run(EntityConsumerLuceneWorkProducer.java:104)
at org.hibernate.search.batchindexing.impl.OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.run(OptionallyWrapInJTATransaction.java:132)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think the above error comes from the mass indexer. First of all, the MassIndexer is only reading data, not persisting it. Secondly, the code you are showing is supposed to index the entity User, but the error comes from persisting the entity Contract. My guess more is going on there than we can see in your post.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to occur when you attempt to persist an entity whose ID already exists.  If it you intend that the MassIndexer would update Contract records, in the error given, then I believe you would want to change the CascadeType annotation to: `CascadeType.ALL` (or perhaps `CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE`).

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code), which discusses this exception further.