# Best way to replace an entity using EntityManager

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I'm using the JPA EntityManager to do some operations, and one such operation is replacing an entity with another entity that has the same `@Id`. So, given an `oldObject` and a `newObject`, what's the best way to remove the `oldObject` and replace it with the `newObject`?

Here's some code that doesn't work:

```
try
{
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.remove(oldObject);
    entityManager.persist(newObject);
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (PersistenceException persistExc)
{
    entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
    // do some stuff
}
```

This code gets the following exception:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.depressio.SomeObject
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1215)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1148)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1154)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:678)
```

Now, of course it works OK if instead of removing the entity, I just update its fields that have changed. However, I'm just being given the new object (the UI is tossing it at me via REST), so I really don't have any clue what fields have changed, so I'd have to update *every* field. If there's a ton of fields, that's not ideal.

I think I'm a little confused as to how to actually do a delete properly. I thought `EntityManager.remove` was the right way, but I guess not.

Thanks in advance!

Edit 1: I feel I should note that oldObject.id == newObject.id. The `id` is generated through a `@SequenceGenerator`. Am I allowed to persist objects with identifiers if their identifier is annotated with a generator already?

Edit 2: According to the top upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code), because the `@Id` is already defined and it's an auto-generated field, Hibernate is deeming it detached. Now I know *why* I get the exception, but the solution is still unclear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what `EntityManager.merge()` does. Pass it the new, detached entity, and it will merge its state to the old, attached entity. The detached entity will stay detached, and the old one will stay attached, but have its state replaced by the state of the new, detached one.

Comment: Oh god, that's embarrassing. For some reason, I assumed `merge` only worked with attached entities, not detached ones. I guess it can work for both, huh? Anyway, that resolves the issue... so silly of me. Thanks!

Comment: merging an attached entity doesn't do anything, except cascading the merge to associations annotated with cascade MERGE or ALL.

Comment: What if I modify the attached entity? Do I even have to merge since it's attached? I get the impression that no, I don't.

Comment: No. An attached entity's state is automatically made persistent by JPA. So if you do `attached = em.merge(detached); attached.setFoo("hello");`, the database row will have the state of `detached`, except for the column foo, wich will have the value "hello".

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the tips! Still learning the magic behind JPA and trying to break my brain from its entrenched position of running native Oracle SQL scripts. :P