# Can't persist with Hibernate and 3 relationed tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persist

I have 3 tables:

**Principals**: PK -> PrincipalID

**Roles_type**: PK -> roles_type

**Roles**: PK -> PrincipalID (Foreign Key), PK -> Role (Foreign Key).

My Entity are:

**PRINCIPALS**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "principals")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Principals implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PrincipalID", nullable = false)
    private String principalID;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "principals")
    private Collection<Roles> rolesCollection;
}
```

**ROLES**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Roles implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @EmbeddedId
    protected RolesPK rolesPK;
    @Column(name = "RoleGroup")
    private String roleGroup;
    @JoinColumn(name = "Role", referencedColumnName = "roles_type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private RolesType rolesType;
    @JoinColumn(name = "PrincipalID", referencedColumnName = "PrincipalID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Principals principals;
}
```

**ROLESPK**

```
@Embeddable
public class RolesPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "PrincipalID", nullable = false)
    private String principalID;
    @Column(name = "Role", nullable = false)
    private String role;
}
```

**ROLES_TYPE**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles_type")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class RolesType implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "roles_type")
    private String rolesType;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "rolesType")
    private Collection<Roles> rolesCollection;
}
```

My code for persist a new principals:

```
Principals principals = new Principals();
principals.setPrincipalID("PRINCIPAL");

RolesType rolesType = em.find(RolesType.class, "TYPE_1");

RolesPK rolesPk = new RolesPK();
rolesPk.setPrincipalID(principals.getPrincipalID());
rolesPk.setRole(rolesType.getRolesType());

Collection<Roles> collRoles = new ArrayList<Roles>();
Roles roles  = new Roles();
roles.setRolesType(rolesType);
roles.setRolesPK(rolesPk);
roles.setPrincipals(principals);

collRoles.add(roles);
principals.setRolesCollection(collRoles);
rolesType.setRolesCollection(collRoles);

em.persist(principals);
```

So I get: 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: package.entity.Principals

I tried many combinations (persist roles, change CascadeType etc...)

Please help me :-)

Comment: Did you try some search? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:
I changed Principals.java from

```
    @Id
    @javax.persistence.GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "PrincipalID", nullable = false)
```

to

```
  @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PrincipalID")
```