# JPA Derived Identity: Detached entity passed to persist

Tags: jpa, inheritance, entity, composite-primary-key, persist

I have a somewhat complicated entity relationship and I cannot figure out the problem of detached entity related to derived identity. I came across similar posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist/), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code), but the problem I have is somewhat more complex.

My entities are like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FISCAL_ARRANGEMENT")
public abstract class FiscalArrangement implements Serializable {

   protected Long id;
   protected String title;
   protected Company operator;
   protected List<Contract> contracts;

   @Id
   @Column(name = "ID")
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   public Long getId() {
      return id;
   }

   @NotNull
   @Column(name = "TITLE")
   public String getTitle() {
     return title;
   }

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "fiscalArrangement", fetch = FetchType.EAGER,  cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.MERGE)
   public List<Contract> getContracts() {
      return contracts;
   }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "CRUDE_TYPE")
public class CrudeType implements Serializable {

    private String code;
    private String crudeType;    
    private List<Contract> contracts;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODE")
    public String getCode() {return code;}

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "crudeType", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    public List<Contract> getContracts() {
        return contracts;
    }
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ContractPK.class)
@Table(name = "CONTRACT")
public abstract class Contract implements Serializable {
    private FiscalArrangement fiscalArrangement;
    private CrudeType crudeType;
    private String title;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "FISCALARRANGEMENTID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public FiscalArrangement getFiscalArrangement() {
        return fiscalArrangement;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CRUDETYPECODE", referencedColumnName = "CODE")
    public CrudeType getCrudeType() {
        return crudeType;
    }
}


public class ContractPK implements Serializable {
    private Long fiscalArrangement;
    private String crudeType;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ForecastPK.class)
@Table(name = "FORECAST")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "FTYPE")
public abstract class Forecast implements Serializable {
    private Integer periodYear;
    private Integer periodMonth;
    private Contract contract;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERIOD_YEAR")
    public Integer getPeriodYear() {
        return periodYear;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "PERIOD_MONTH")
    public Integer getPeriodMonth() {
        return periodMonth;
    }

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "FISCALARRANGEMENTID"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "CRUDETYPECODE")
    })
    public Contract getContract() {
        return contract;
    }
}

public class ForecastPK implements Serializable {        
    private Integer periodYear;
    private Integer periodMonth;
    private ContractPK contract;
}
```

The following are sub-classes:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("REG")
public class RegularContract extends Contract{}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("REG")
public class RegularForecast extends Forecast {}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("JV")
public class JointVenture extends FiscalArrangement {}
```

In my controller class,I perform the following:

```
Contract selected = new RegularContract();
selected.setFiscalArrangement(fiscalArrangement);
selected.setCrudeType(crudeType);
em.merge(selected);
```

The object reference fiscalArrangement and crudeType are already persisted entities selected from a drop-down menu and passed to the above code snippet

Then I get the following errors:

```
20:32:13,846 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-58) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component ContractServicesImpl for method public abstract void com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.AbstractCrudServices.edit(java.lang.Object): javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.nnpcgroup.cosm.entity.JointVenture
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:187)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:277)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.contract.ContractServices$$$view64.edit(Unknown Source)
at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.controller.ContractController.persist(ContractController.java:190)
at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.controller.ContractController.create(ContractController.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.el.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:181)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxHandler.java:459)
at javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent.processListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent.java:113)
at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:106)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:805)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.nnpcgroup.cosm.entity.JointVenture
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1608)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.merge(AbstractEntityManager.java:565)
at com.nnpcgroup.cosm.ejb.impl.AbstractCrudServicesImpl.edit(AbstractCrudServicesImpl.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
... 88 more
    Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.nnpcgroup.cosm.entity.JointVenture
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer$IncrediblySillyJpaMapsIdMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:384)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:219)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4601)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:148)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:69)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:840)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:822)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:827)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1161)
... 119 more
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: you didn't bother printing the correct stack trace. See that nested exception at the bottom ... print its stack trace!

Comment: The code you've provided shows nothing about the fiscalArrangement or crudeType you pointing Contract to.  Since these are bidirectional relationships, those entity's lists will need to have the Contract added to them and the changes merged or the cached objects will be out of synch with the changes you are trying to push to the database.

Comment: Full stack trace now added! Thanks.

Comment: @Chris I guess you are referring to the code below:

Contract selected = new RegularContract();
selected.setFiscalArrangement(fiscalArrangement);
selected.setCrudeType(crudeType);
em.merge(selected);

The fiscalArrangement and crudeType reference are already persisted objects selected from a drop-down menu and passed to the method that performs the code snippet above.

Comment: Actually the fiscalArrangement is pointing to a subtype of FiscalArrangement entity: JointVenture;

In other words the entity JointVenture extends FiscalArrangement.

Comment: Was this fixed?