# JPA/Hibernate detached entity passed to persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa, persistence, h2, ejb-3.0

new to JPA and hibernate, so please bear with me as I try to draw up a whole pic. So I have two Java objects that have bidirectional relationship. Employee class is the owning class and Department class is the inverse side of the relationship. A department can have many employees and a employee can have only one department. I assigned employee_id to be the primary key of the employee entity and department_id as the primary key of the department entity. I also want to use department_id as the foreign key in the employee class.

Employee class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Employee")
    public class Employee
    implements java.io.Serializable
    {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       //primary key
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
       @Column(name = "Employee_ID")
       private Integer       id;

       //foreign key 
       @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
       @JoinColumn(name = "Department_ID")
       private Department department;

       @Column(name = "Employee_name")
       private String    name;

       public Employee() { }

       public Employee(Integer id)
       {
          this.setId(id);
       }

       public void setDepartment(Department department){
           this.department = department;
       }
       public Department getDepartment(){
           return department;
       }
       public Integer getId() { return id; }
       public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
       public String getEmployeeName(){
            return name;
        }

        public void setEmployeeName(String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
```

Department class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Department")
public class Department
implements java.io.Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "Department_ID")
   private Integer       id;

   @Column(name = "Department_name")
   private String    name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="department", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   private Collection<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

   public Collection<Employee> getEmployees() {return employees;}
   public void setEmployees(Collection<Employee> e){ employees = e;}

   public Department() { }

   public Department(Integer id)
   {
      this.setId(id);
   }

   public Integer getId() { return id; }
   public void setId(Integer id) { this.id = id; }
   public String getDepartmentName(){
        return name;
    }

    public void setDepartmentName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
```

Function I use to generate two objects and persist them in the database. The database I am testing with is H2 and the persistence.xml file is configured to drop all the tables initially so all tables is empty before the below function is called.

```
public static void populateTable() {
        System.out.println("Populating tables");
        Department d1 = new Department();
        //d1.setId(1);
        d1.setDepartmentName("finance");
        //service.addDepartment(d1);

        Employee e1 = new Employee();
        e1.setEmployeeName("John");
        //e1.setId(1);
        //e1.setDepartment(d1);
        //d1.getEmployees().add(e1);
        service.addDepartment(d1);
        service.addEmployee(e1);
}
```

Initially I tried to set the primary ids of created objects myself and I was getting "detached entity passed to persist" error. After reading a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442036/3444882), I understand that if I try to set the unique identifier before persisting the object, JPA will think the entity is already present in the database and it will throw a "detached entity passed to persist error". So I commented out callers to setter functions and above code runs fine. However if I try to link an employee to a department like what I did with `e1.setDepartment(d1);` I would get this error `detached entity passed to persist: com.javatunes.jpa.catalog.Department`. I have read many blogs such as [this one](http://meri-stuff.blogspot.com/2012/03/jpa-tutorial.html#RelationshipsBidirectionalOneToManyManyToOneConsistency) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13370221/jpa-hibernate-detached-entity-passed-to-persist), but I still cannot find a solution to this problem. And one more thing the two persisting functions are defined as

```
public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
          em.persist(employee);
          em.flush();
          }

public void addDepartment(Department department){
          em.persist(department);
          em.flush();
          }
```

The error is raised at em.persistent(employee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your Employee entity, you have configured Department to Cascade ALl 
which means whenever Employee entity is `PERSIST, MERGE, REMOVE, REFRESH, DETACH` will do the same for Department.

Now coming back to your problem. In your `populateTable` function 
you have created `Department` and `Employee` entity 
you need to link `Department` and `Employee` like this

```
e1.setDepartment(d1);
```

and finally persist employee which will persist both Employee and Department for you

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem in my spring boot project but the solution here worked with ease. I realized you will always get the detached persistence exception whenever you persist a child object before the parent i.e You should never place the Cascade.ALL constraint on the child entity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is your service class. Since your service class is `@Transactional` when you save `d1` `service.addDepartment(d1);` then when the function returns then `d1` gets detached and it is no longer in persistent state and then in the next line when you try to save `e1` `service.addEmployee(e1);` including `d1.getEmployees().add(e1)`, then you will obviously get `detached entity passed to persist:` this error. Because your `d1` object is already in detached state and you are trying to persist this in another `@Transactional` method. I think either you can merge the two service methods into one to save department and employee and this error can be simply ignored or you can use `merge` operation in next service method like this:

```
public void addDepartment(Department department) {
    em.merge(department);
    em.flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ashish451, the error lies in the fact that in my service code, I persisted department (d1). However, if I try to link employee (e1) and department (d1) first and then persist the employee, the JPA will not be happy because department (d1) has already been persisted and `persist()` only works on transient object or newly created instance.