# org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "student")
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Setter
@Getter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    int id;
    @Column(name = "first_name")
    String firstName;
    @Column(name = "last_name")
    String lastName;
    @Column(name = "email")
    String email;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, String email) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

```
@Repository
public class StudentDaoImpl implements StudentDao{

    private final EntityManager manager;

    @Autowired
    public StudentDaoImpl(EntityManager manager){
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void save(Student student) {
        manager.persist(student);
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class CrudDemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(StudentDao studentDao){
        return runner ->{
        createStudent(studentDao);
        };
    }
    private void createStudent(StudentDao studentDao) {
        Student student = new Student("Shamil", "Azakhov", "shamilazakhov@gmail.com");
        studentDao.save(student);
        System.out.println("Student's id: " + student.getId());
    }
}
```

```
                 And my application.properties file
```

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/student_tracker
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=secret
```

```
      Exception that has been throwed
```

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute statement [ERROR: relation "student" does not exist
> Position: 13] [insert into student (email,first_name,last_name) values (?,?,?)]; SQL [insert into student (email,first_name,last_name) values (?,?,?)]
>
> at com.luv2code.cruddemo.CrudDemoApplication.createStudent(CrudDemoApplication.java:27) ~[classes/:na]
> at com.luv2code.cruddemo.CrudDemoApplication.lambda$commandLineRunner$0(CrudDemoApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
>
> Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement [ERROR: relation "student" does not exist
> Position: 13] [insert into student (email,first_name,last_name) values (?,?,?)]
>
> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "student" does not exist

The code works for mysql but not for postgresql. I couldn't figure out why
As you see in code snippets that I gave just 3 parameters to Student object (name, surname, email) I didn't give id.
But when I give id also it outputs the following exception -->

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.luv2code.cruddemo.entity.Student
> Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.luv2code.cruddemo.entity.Student

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error message `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "student" does not exist` occur in next cases as I know.

1. The table `student` does not exist at all in your database.(You have to create it).
2. The name of table that you have in database not match the naming that you put on `Entity` `@Table(name = "student")`. As example you
   have declared `student` but in database it is named as `students`.
3. You have not declared the schema where the table exists.  As example default one is `public` but you maybe have another custom
   one.

About second error that you are getting:
`org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.luv2code.cruddemo.entity.Student`

I guess a relevant answers about it you can get from this `Q/A`: [detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441598/detached-entity-passed-to-persist-error-with-jpa-ejb-code) from stackoverflow.

Comment: Thanks so much for help
In mysql the table created with id auto_increment
But in postgresql I didn't.
In postgres it should be created with id serial primary key but created it with id int primary key.

Comment: If my answer really help, don`t forget to accept it for future if someone will have the same problem as your.